# RPI OpenGL PWM display driver

Tags: opengl, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi4

So I'm building a system based on a raspberry pi 4 running Linux (image created through buildroot) driving a Led matrix (64x32 RGB connectors) and I'm very confused about the software stack of linux. I'd like to be able to use OpenGL capabilities on a small resolution screen that would then be transfered to a driver that would actually drive the Led matrix.

I've read about DRM, KMS, GEM and other systems and I've concluded the best way to go about it would be to have the following working scheme:

```
User space:      App
                  | OpenGL
                  v
Kernel space:    DRM -GEM-> Led device driver
                                  |
                                  v
Hardware:                     Led Matrix
```

Some of this may not make a lot of sense since the concepts are still confusing to me.

Essentially, the app would make OpenGL calls that would generate frames that could be mapped to buffers on the DRM which could be shared with the Led device driver which would then drive the leds in the matrix.

Would something like this be the best way about it?

I could just program some dumb buffer cpu implementation but I'd rather take this as a learning experience.

Comment: For which hardware interface? DSI? LVDS? SPI?

Comment: No interface, it is programmed by timed latching of the 8 inputs, but that's not the focus of the question

Comment: I would not create my own display driver. I would simply use an OpenGL off screen buffer(or use Vulkan) and transfer it through other ways to the LED matrix. Turning your LED matrix into a display detected as a HDMI display is very complicated and not maintainable and should therefore only be a hobby challenge. If you need to run any application on your display, I would consider writing your wayland compositor or X server. It would then not use the HDMI display framebuffer, but copy it to your LED matrix.

Comment: @NoNae Thank you very much for your reply! I think your reply may be very close to what I'm trying to do. Could you elaborate more on how the openGL off screen buffer would work with the wayland compositor/X server? I would accept that as an answer for the question

Comment: You really really don't want to bother writing a display driver (unless you are designing your own graphics card). Just use the normal display system and then read the pixels that it creates.

Comment: @user253751 I think I used the wrong terminology for what I wanted. Even so, I don't see the problem being that simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL renders into a buffer (called "framebuffer" that is usually displayed onto the screen. But rendering into an off screen buffer (as the name implies) does not render onto the screen but into an array, which can be read by C/C++. There is one indirection on modern operating systems. Usually you have multiple windows visible on your screen. Therefore the application can't render onto the screen itself but into a buffer maneged by the windowing system, which is then composited into one final image. Linux uses Wayland, multiple Wayland clients can create and draw into the Wayland compositor's buffers.

If you only want to display your application just use a off screen buffer.

If you want to display another application read it's framebuffer by writing your own Wayland compositor. Note this may be hard (I've never done that) if you want to use hardware acceleration.